# Bind MPAndroidChart library to Visual Studio 2015 for Xamarin

Tags: visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android, mpandroidchart

I need to use the library [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) in Visual Studio 2015 Xamarin. Could anyone demonstrate how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MPAndroidChart is available in [this NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MPAndroidChart/3.0.1) for Xamarin:

As per the instructions in the link, in [Package Manager Console](https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/tools/package-manager-console) type the following:

> Install-Package MPAndroidChart